# Converting in mssql and row select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a serious question about mssql now..

You see, there's a query made to select some values from an actual number in UInt64

```
 DECLARE @val bigint = 33689413311;
WHILE ( @val > 0 )
 BEGIN
  PRINT CONVERT(varchar(max),((@val%32)*100)/31)+'%'
  SET @val = @val/32
 END
```

The result of this query should be:

100%

67%

29%

74%

0%

38%

100%

Now, I want this query to select only the top 100%, and not to print the other (67,29,74,0,38,100)

Is there any method to do it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange request.  What you have isn't a "query".  It is t-sql code.  If you just want the first value, get rid of the `while` loop:

```
DECLARE @val bigint = 33689413311;
PRINT CONVERT(varchar(max),((@val%32)*100)/31)+'%'
```

Comment: Okay, what if I want to show '67%' or '29%' *what I mean exactly, selecting whatever of the result value I want to show to be specified into one line only*.. is that possible?